# Personalizar componentes en gvNix

Tags: spring-mvc, gvnix, spring-roo

Me gustaría saber como podría modificar los componentes y valores que quiero que se muestren en en la página.

Por un lado me gustaria poder editar los valores de un registro desde la tabla de las listas y guardar la edicion.

Por otro lado me gustaria mostrar en un combobox el nombre o descripcion de mi campo "hijo (Fk)"

Quisiera saber que archivos sean xml, jspx y/o java tener en cuenta a la hora de editar para poder personalizarlos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Echa un ojo al [manual de usuario de gvNIX](http://www.gvnix.org//assets/doc/gvnix-1.5.1.RC4-reference-docs.pdf) y a [los ejemplos de quick-start](https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/tree/master/quickstart-geo-app/), sobretodo a los apartados del componente Datatables y el componente Lupa.

Para poder darte una respuesta más concreta es necesario acotar un poco mas la pregunta.

¡Suerte!